# How to import GraphQLUpload in nest.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, image, graphql, nestjs

I am trying to write a GraphQL mutation to upload image in nestjs framework

I have search through google for multiple solution.

One of the solution suggest that using an npm package

```
graphql-upload
```

to add a GraphQLUpload type for uploading

However, I tried to run

```
npm install graphql-upload
```

gives error:

```
npm ERR! While resolving: my-project@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: graphql@15.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/graphql
npm ERR!   graphql@"^15.8.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer graphql@"^16.3.0" from graphql-upload@16.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/graphql-upload
npm ERR!   graphql-upload@"*" from the root project
```

I realize my graphql version maybe too old to support the graphql-upload

Then I tried to update my graphql version with

```
npm install graphql@"16.3.0"
```

which makes me successful to install graphql-upload afterwards

However, when I try:

```
import { GraphQLUpload } from 'graphql-upload';
```

Error occurs with the follow console output

```
Module '"graphql-upload"' has no exported member 'GraphQLUpload'.
```

May I know what is the way to solve this problem

Or are there any better ways to upload image to nestjs with graphql

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach. In the newer versions of graphql-upload they use different module standart. My IDE was giving me import errors so i just ignored them.

Install graphql-upload@13.0.0 so you can use default imports.

**main.ts**

```
// Ignore the import error
// @ts-ignore
import { graphqlUploadExpress } from 'graphql-upload';


    async function bootstrap() {
      // Set app to use graphql-upload
      app.use(graphqlUploadExpress({maxFileSize: 1000000, maxFiles: 10 }));
      // Rest of the code
    }
```

**upload.resolver.ts**

```
import { Args, Mutation, Resolver } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { createWriteStream } from 'fs';
// Ignore the import errors
// @ts-ignore
import { GraphQLUpload, FileUpload } from 'graphql-upload';

@Resolver()
export class UploadResolver {
  @Mutation(() => Boolean)
  async singleUpload(
    @Args({ name: 'file', type: () => GraphQLUpload })
    { createReadStream, filename }: FileUpload,
  ) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =>
      createReadStream()
        .pipe(createWriteStream(`./uploads/${filename}`))
        .on('finish', () => resolve(true))
        .on('error', () => reject(false)),
    );
  }
}
```

Create the 'uploads' folder in the root directory;

To test it I use Insomnia. Here is my query settings:

```
operations: { "query": "mutation ($file: Upload!) { singleUpload(file: $file) }", "variables": { "file": null } }

map: { "0": ["variables.file"] }

0: // Your file
```

[image: Here is the reuslt]